# Optimizing mysql fulltext search

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I want to make a search with fulltext in my web. I need the search with a pagination. my database have 50,000+ rows/per table.  I have alter my table and make `(title,content,date)` to be index. the table is always update, there still have a column `id` which is automatic increase. and the latest `date` is always at the end of table.

```
date  varchar(10)
title  text
content  text
```

but whole query time will cost `1.5+ seconds`. I search the many articles via google, some wrote that only limit `Index` field word length can help the search more quickly. but as a `text` type, it `can not` alter a certain length like that( i have tried `ALTER TABLE table_1 CHANGE`titletitle`TEXT(500) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL`, not work)

```
date  varchar(10)
title  text(500)
content  text(1000)
```

so, Except `Sphinx` and third part script. how to optimization fulltext search with only sql? query code here:

```
(SELECT 
title,content,date 
FROM table_1 
WHERE MATCH (title,content,date) 
AGAINST ('+$Search' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
UNION 
(SELECT 
title,content,date 
FROM table_2 
WHERE MATCH (title,content,date) 
AGAINST ('+$Search' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
Order By date DESC
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are there frequent changes to the data in the table? Or here changes at all? An Inverted Index will always speed full-test-search up incredibly and for static data, it is incredibly easy to implement / apply. If there are updates, this may become more complicated

Comment: @b.buchhold,yes, the data in the table are frequent update, changes. So it is difficulty... at least I do not have any good idea. so ask for a help, if anyone has a wise method.

Comment: Is it a full text index on (title,content,date), or a btree index?

Comment: @Denis, just `alter table table_1 ADD INDEX title(title)`.

Comment: What's the reason you can't use something like Lucene for this? It's implemented in pure PHP through the Zend Framework

Comment: **Caution:  The timing of this Q&A implies that it is talking only about MyISAM.  Its applicability to InnoDB is in question.**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on the question's follow-up comments, you've a btree index on your columns rather than a full text index.

For MATCH (title,content) against search, you would need:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX index_name ON tbl_name (title,content);
```

I'm not sure it'll accept the date field in there (the latter is probably not relevant anyway).

Comment: I think adding date to the FULLTEXT index is OK in this instance since the date is a varchar(10) and not a datetime field. Also, not having a FULLTEXT from the start was a dead giveaway. +1 for you !!!

Comment: sorry for a later reply. this will faster than `alter table table_1 ADD INDEX title(title)` I still have some questions. 1. is the query change into `SELECT  title,content,date  FROM table_1  WHERE MATCH (index_name)  AGAINST ('+$Search' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` or still `MATCH (title,content,date)`? what is the `index_name` usage? 2.If I created a new table, something like this? `CREATE TABLE table_1  (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
title TEXT,
content TEXT,
date VARCHAR(10),
FULLTEXT (title,content,date)
);` Thanks again.

Comment: @Yuli: just create the indexes on the current tables: `create fulltext index yourtable_fulltext_idx on yourtable(title,content,date);` and then run your current query.

Answer (score 6):

I have a comprehensive plan for you to optimize MySQL for FULLTEXT indexing as thoroughly as possible

The first thing you should do is : **Get rid of the stopword list**

This has annoyed some people over the years because of being unaware that [over 600 words are excluded from a FULLTEXT index](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/full-text-revealed.html#stopwords).

[Here is tabular view of those stopwords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html).

There are two ways to bypass this

Bypass Option 1) Create a custom stopword list.

You can actually submit to mysql a list of your preferred stopwords. Here is the default:

```
mysql> show variables like 'ft%';
+--------------------------+----------------+
| Variable_name            | Value          |
+--------------------------+----------------+
| ft_boolean_syntax        | + -><()~*:""&| |
| ft_max_word_len          | 84             |
| ft_min_word_len          | 4              |
| ft_query_expansion_limit | 20             |
| ft_stopword_file         | (built-in)     |
+--------------------------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

OK, not let's create our stopword list. I usually set the English articles as the only stopwords.

```
echo "a"    > /var/lib/mysql/stopwords.txt
echo "an"  >> /var/lib/mysql/stopwords.txt
echo "the" >> /var/lib/mysql/stopwords.txt
```

Next, add the option to /etc/my.cnf plus allowing 1-letter, 2-letter, and 3 letter words

```
[mysqld]
ft_min_word_len=1
ft_stopword_file=/var/lib/mysql/stopwords.txt
```

Finally, restart  mysql

```
service mysql restart
```

If you have any tables with FULLTEXT indexes already in place, you must drop those FULLTEXT indexes and create them again.

Bypass Option 2) Recompile the source code

The filename is storage/myisam/ft_static.c. Just alter the C structure that holds the 600+ words so that it is empty. Having fun recompiling !!!

Now that the FULLTEXT config is solidified, here is another major aspect to consider:

**Write proper refactored queries so that the MySQL Query Optimizer works right !!!**

What I am now mentioning is really undocumented: Whenever you perform queries that do JOINs and the WHERE clause contains the MATCH function for FULLTEXT searching, it tends to cause the MySQL Query Optimizer to treat the query like a full table scan when it comes to searching the columns invoved in the FULLTEXT index. If you plan to query a table using a FULLTEXT index, [ALWAYS refactor your query to have the FULLTEXT search return only keys in a subquery and connect those keys to your main table](http://www.webmasterworld.com/databases_sql_mysql/4229410.htm). Otherwise, the FULLTEXT index will put the MySQL Query Optimizer in a tailspin.

Comment: Option one is always a good idea since each corpus (collection of text elements to query) has its own stopword requirements as well as the goal of querying.

Comment: Option two isn't a good idea for a great number of reasons, not the least of which is after the recommended procedure you would be running a custom, non-upgradeable version of Mysql.

Answer (score 1):

For further ideas regarding full-text search optimization in MySQL, see [How to optimize MySQL Boolean Full-Text Search? (Or what to replace it with?) - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034976/how-to-optimize-mysql-boolean-full-text-search-or-what-to-replace-it-with-c/6146107#6146107)