# fulltext index being ignored in Boolean Mode when used with number of words conditional

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

fulltext match is ignoring its index when I add a number of words conditional for its boolean mode. The selects are as follows:

```
explain select * from seeds  WHERE  MATCH(text) AGAINST ("mount cameroon" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

outputs

```
+----+-------------+-------+----------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type     | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+----------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | seeds | fulltext | text          | text | 0       |      |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+----------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

the same query with a number of words conditional

```
explain select * from seeds  WHERE  MATCH(text) AGAINST ("mount cameroon" IN BOOLEAN MODE) = 4;
```

outputs

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | seeds | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 9607 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

surely this cant be correct behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

The diagnosis is that the Mysql optimizer is readily confused when any condition is added to a fulltext MATCH. Solution is to refactor the query (split into subqueries and join).

This diagnosis and solution is kindly provided by RolandoMySQLDBA (https://stackoverflow.com/users/491757/rolandomysqldba), and availablein full  here

[Optimizing mysql fulltext search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070993/optimizing-mysql-fulltext-search/6092216#6092216),

and here

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7136/fulltext-index-ignored-in-boolean-mode-with-number-of-words-conditional.