# Would search speed improve if related data was held in a separate table?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, database-design, innodb

We have table

```
Article
(
    id, 
    user_id, 
    date_created, 
    date_from, 
    date_to, 
    title, 
    description, 
    latitude, 
    longitude
)
```

If we were to separate the title and description data into another table like this, how significantly would searching improve if we had 10,000,000 articles.

ArticleContent(article_id, title, description)

What is the cruical factor here that would increase searching speed noticeably?

** UPDATE **

- by searching i mean full-text search
- title: varchar(50), description: TEXT

** UPDATE **

- mysql version 5.5
- storage engine used innoDB ( So no fulltext indexing support )

Comment: What are the lengths (expected average and median for those of variable-length) of the columns?

Comment: title: varchar(50), description: TEXT. Though for title probably a lot less than 50

Comment: Also, by "searching" are you talking full-text search, or indexed lookups on some field(s)?

Comment: Would creating a FULLTEXT index like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070993/optimizing-mysql-fulltext-search increase performance significantly?

Comment: Almost anything you do will help to start. (Because the default techniqu willl be so atrociously slow.) As you progress to more complicated support mechanisms, it may matter more which methods yo combine.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know of databases, I don't think it would make any difference. The important thing is to make sure the fields you want to search on are indexed.

I have used a table with a similar number of rows and searching is very fast. (Although none of the fields is as long as I imagine `description` is.)

Answer (score 0):

For full-text search it won't make any significant difference storing the data in one or two tables.

You will need some sort of full-text support, such as indexed key words, inorder to get any significant performance gain over the default table-scan. I don't know how much support like that is available in MySql.